# wsdl schema namespace prefix is changing in different environments - AXIS2

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, xml-namespaces, wsdl2java, java2wsdl

I deployed a component having SOAP webservices in an Open Nebula recently. After deployment, we noticed the WSDL responses to be having a different **namespace prefix**

Problem: AlertBot was expecting to see
`<ax25:response>TEST</ax25:response>`
but, it started seeing
`<ax21:response>TEST</ax21:response>` instead. We compared the build between the new and old host, and saw no differences in config files, or the java package.

**We need to figure out why the ax25 part namespace prefix got changed to ax21 on the new host**

**NOTE: We use AXIS2 library for generating WSDLs**

Comment: the prefix is most likely generated. as long as the actual namespace did not change in the message the prefix can be anything. you should never look for a string with a specific prefix but use a proper xml parser.

Comment: yes @martijn , but I still would like to understand why the namespace prefix will change just when we deploy in a new environment.